# How to have dropdown selection populate in page code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model full of records.  I want a user to be able to select one of these items from a dropdown menu.  When selected, I want it to provide that record for use on the page.  It can be by a partial or any means. Changing the selected item, updates items on the page each time

I tried the render_async gem, but couldn't get the events call to work.  Using plain javascript I can call the value of an option, but not pull the record itself.

Comment: Can you please add some code for plain javascript?

Comment: Did you populate the select field with the records ???? if so when selecting the option run a js function which fetches the value or text inside the selected option to update the item on the page.

Answer (score 0):

To pull the record you could use a form and submit it through javascript. For example if your model is called Product you could do in the view where you have the dropdown/select:

```
= form_tag(products_path, method: :get, remote: true) do
  = select_tag :product, options_for_select(Product.all.map { |product| [product.name, product.id] }, selected: params[:product] ), include_blank: 'All products', class: '', onchange: 'document.getElementById("submitFilter").click();'
  = button_tag(type: 'submit', id: 'submitFilter', class: 'd-none')
```

When you select an product it will do a GET request to the products path so in the products controller index action you also need to respond to JS and you need an index.js.haml (or .erb) where you handle the data and update the view.

example products controller:

```rb
def index
  @products = Product.all
  if params[:product]
    @product = Product.find(params[:product])
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

example view:

```
#product
  = render 'product'
```

example index.js.haml

```js
$("#product").html("#{escape_javascript(render 'product')}")
```

For this example you will need a partial _product.html.haml that holds the data.